# If inside a while loop

Tags: java

```
public class BeerSong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int beerNum = 99;
        String word = "bottles";
        while (beerNum > 0) {
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer.");
            System.out.println("Take one down.");
            System.out.println("Pass it around.");
            beerNum = beerNum - 1;
            if (beerNum == 1) {
                word = "bottle";  // singular, as in ONE bottle.
            }
            if (beerNum > 0) {
                System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
            }  // end else
        } // end while loop
    }  // end main method
}  // end class
```

This code prints out:

```
99 bottles of beer on the wall
99 bottles of beer on the wall.
99 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around.
```

Why doesn't it print like this:

```
99 bottles of beer on the wall
99 bottles of beer. 
Take one down and pass it around, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
```

Since the if statement is after the loop

Comment: "This code prints out:" No it doesn't. It will print `Take one down.` and `Pass it around.` on separate lines, without the `and` and with different capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: The `if` statement _isn't_ after the loop. It is inside the loop.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? It seems correct although it doesn't print as you want, as already pointed out by Andy Turner. Change your 3rd and 4th print statement ( `System.out.println("Take one down.");` and `System.out.println("Pass it around.");`) to  `System.out.print("Take one down and pass it around, ");` and you should almost be done.

Answer (score 0):

this condition iswhat is breaking the code:

```
if (beerNum > 0) {
        System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the     wall");
} else {
        System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
} // end else
```

you are checkin the bottles and printing if the number is not zero...

you should replace that logic for something like:

```
if (beerNum == 0) {
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
}
```

after that the song will be played well :)

the final code could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int beerNum = 99;
String word = "bottles";
while (beerNum > 0) {
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer.");
    System.out.println("Take one down.");
    System.out.println("Pass it around.");
    beerNum = beerNum - 1;
    if (beerNum == 1) {
    word = "bottle"; // singular, as in ONE bottle.
    } else if (beerNum == 0) {
    word = "bottles";
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: if no beer is left you write `0 bottles of beer on the wall` how does that improve anything?

Comment: The condition seems correct. If `beerNum` is 0 (i.e. it is not greater than 0 - the else branch) he wants to print "No more bottles of beer on the wall". Your fix would break that.